# Database normalization - is this the right thing to do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

So me and one my team mate's have an argument about a database design we are doing to normalize another database.

The external data warehouse has the following flat table:

Table `Customer`:

```
customerID int not null unique pk auto_increment
customerName varchar(255) not null
.....
whole lot of columns here in a flat manner 
   (which should go to the appropriate tables when normalized)
```

The current data is in this external table (a linked server).

Our task, is creating a program the creates new quotes to customers based on historical data.

My team mate has designed the following two tables:

Table `CustomerHistory`:

```
c_id int not null unique pk auto_increment
customerID int not null
customerName varchar(255) not null
```

Table `Quote`:

```
quoteID int not null unique pk auto_increment
c_id int not null unique pk auto_increment
dtCreateDate datetime now()
```

When I've seen this I was shocked.

How could you ignore a perfectly valid PK and create a new one on top of it?

Even if you did that, how can you do it without a Datetime/timestamp of some kind to point to the changes?

My team mate explained:

> I cannot trust the data that comes from the Data warehouse and therefor I create new id's

when asked about tracking the time changes he replied:

> no need, since I am taking snapshots of the database on each change

I was amazed by this.

Then I offered the following solution:

Table `CustomerHistory`:

```
customerID int not null
customerName varchar(255) not null
dtChanged datetime
composite key on customerID and dtChanged
```

This way, I figured, we can query the table for any given quote and the time it was issued with the correct customer and he's name.

My team mate keeps arguing that his method is "fail safe" and we already delayed the project by two weeks for this.

Please, could you guys help us to settle this down?

If I am wrong, I am really interested in learning why, if I am right well, good for me ;)

**EDIT:**
Assuming:
1. at any point in time i am required to provide the `customerName` on a `quote` that actually created the quote.
2. Having access to `Customer` table is only for CURRENT customers (and not past)
3. Being able to track `customerName` changes.

Comment: if he thinks his method is failsafe, find a way to make it fail

Comment: "ignore a perfectly valid PK"  "i cannot trust the data" its one or the other.

Comment: @NimChimpsky i agree, but those are the answers i get.

Comment: eh ? its either a valid pk or its not.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus - i cannot think of one, this is why i posted the q.

Comment: @Dementic - why does he not trust the data from DW ? Chenqui.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - i got no answer for that.

Comment: @Dementic - Will you have to justify your design choices to `someone` now or in the future ? If yes, then please ask that person if he/she has faced any issues with the quality of data in the DW.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - the teammate in working in another company that sub-contract our projects. therefore, i will need to justify any failure. while he is "free of responsibility".

Comment: The "Quote" table has two automatically incrementing (identity) columns. SQL Server doesn't allow two identity columns in one table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you will now have three tables:

```
Customer
CustomerHistory
Quote
```

I think your partner has the right idea.  Customer has `customerId` as it's primary key.  `CustomerHistory` is using `customerId` as a foreign key, so it needs it's own primary key (`c_id` in this case?  I would probably try to name it something more sane like just `id` - stop with the smurf naming!)

That leaves your `Quote` table which uses the history's key as a foreign key `c_id`, and adds a new primary key for itself `quoteId`

`CustomerHistory`, however, does NOT NEED a `customerName` field, because that would already be in your `Customer` table.

If you don't need `CustomerHistory` and `Customer` to be two separate tables, then you are right - you can trust the `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraints on just `Customer` - and you don't need to add an additional primary key to it.  `UNIQUE` guarantees that field to be a unique identifier - so if that's what he's "not trusting" then tell him he's wrong :P  However, if you do end up with three tables as above, then he's not quite wrong but his reasoning of "not trusting" something doesn't make sense.

EDIT:

An example query to get a specific customer's quotes from a specific date range will look something like this:

```
SELECT CustomerHistory.customerName, Quote.*
FROM CustomerHistory
INNER JOIN Quote ON (CustomerHistory.c_id = Quote.c_id)
WHERE CustomerHistory.createdOn BETWEEN 'Jan 1, 2010' AND 'Jan 30, 2010'
AND CustomerHistory.customerId = 5000
```

Your composite key might change the query slightly - but honestly I don't think either answer is "right", or "wrong".  I'm not sure what you partner meant when he said he doesn't need timestamps because he's taking a snapshot of the database... You're *both* taking a snapshot, and you should both be recording the date of each field when that snapshot was captured.

I really just think composite keys over-complicate things more than necessary - but that's my personal opinion.  If it works for your situation and the data is exactly what you're looking for when you're done with the changes - then that's what matters ;)  I suspect both will have similar performance assuming you have indices set sanely.

Comment: `customerId` in the `CustomerHistory` is nothing but an indexed column (to speed up queries), i still do not understand ignoring the PK. `CustomerName` might change, and we only keep historical data, so raising a quote from a year before, would have the wrong `customerName` on it.

Comment: is `Customer` still a table in the new schema?  Are you sure that `customerId` isn't supposed to be a foreign key referencing it?  Why would you need to rename it to `CustomerHistory` if it's not actually a history of a customer, but rather a list of customers?

Comment: `Customer` table holds only current data. `CustomerHistory` holds only historical data.

Comment: If it's historical data, then is it true that `CustomerHistory` might have two entries for the same customer?

Comment: yes, but they can be represented by a composite key of `customerID` and the `dtChanged` fields. that is, if `customerName` changed.

Comment: I'm going to be honest - composite keys are a serious *pain in the ass* to work with.  And using a datetime field as one of the keys is just...odd.  I would prefer to go the route of giving it it's own single primary key and let `customerId` tell you which customer it is indicating.  If you have `Quote` referencing your `customerHistory` table - that composite key is just going to keep biting you in the ass.  I can't remember the last time I actuallly used a composite key.  Not since school - 7 years ago.  Even my join tables have their own primary key in addition to the two foreign keys :P

Comment: the question is not how hard it is to use the data model, but how correct it is. i agree that he's method is "easier", i do not agree on "it is the correct thing to do". when you are employed by a company that pays you 60,000 euro to do this, you dont go for the "easy way".

Comment: And I would argue that giving it it's own primary key is "the correct way" and putting a timestamp into a composite key field is "the wrong way".  This is all a bit subjective though.  There's no "one true answer", but the way you phrased you question, and the way you wrote out the table, you DIDN'T make those two fields a composite key.  You made `customerId` the only primary key, and that is going to fail when a new entry is made with the same `customerId`

Comment: you're right, bad writing. but the idea still stands. i am aware that there cannot be two identical pk's in the same table, just a bit upset and rushed into writing this.

Comment: also, taking snapshots of the database are way more expensive then creating the extra columns, you need to add hardware consideration into the equation.

Comment: You'll see in my most recent edit that I still include the date timestamp on `customerHistory`.  From what I understand you intend on creating these normalized entries periodically, based on a point-in-time of the data warehouse - And each time you run it, you are "taking a snapshot" by grabbing the data from the warehouse, and adding new entries to these tables.  Is that correct?  Seems like you still need a timestamp in there.  My recent edit has that timestamp.

Comment: as per your example, we do not hold a `Customer` table. only `CustomerHistory` following your query would result `Bob` as the creator of the quote while it was actually `Alice`.

Comment: I think that I don't fully understand the requirements :\

Comment: Ahh - if the customer was renamed to "Alice" at some point then you would get back the wrong data.

Comment: Exactly! that is what im worried off. printing an invoice for quote 1000 with the wrong name, can be a very bad thing.

Comment: See my edit.  I don't really know what he meant by "snapshot of the database" though :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a discussion topic, you will not get “The” right answer here. All I’ve got are some questions to ask your team mate.

To me, the key factor is: why doesn he mean when he says he does not “…trust the data that comes from the data wareshouse”?

- Is CustomerID unique within the warehouse?
- Can the same CustomerID be assigned to multiple customers?
- Can the CustomerID for a given individual change (same Id, meaning changes over time)?
- Do you get CustomerIDs from multiple sources (allowing for the above two situations)?

If CustomerID can be used to uniquely identify each customer *over time*, then use it. If it cannot, subsequent questions are:

- Do you need to track customer info imported from the warehouse over time?
- If not, then you probably don’t need the (original and unreliable) CustomerID, throw it away.
- If you do, with a changing Id how can you possibly track data for the same customer across multiple imports from the warehouse?

---

[updated after your edit]

Sounds like a logging situation….

- The data source (the warehouse) contains CustomerID and Name
- CustomerID does not change, but Name does
- Periodically, you must copy over data from the warehouse to the new system
- You need to track the Name associated with the CustomerID *as of * the point in time the copy is made
- Therefore, Name is not an attribute of CustomerID (in the new system)
- Rather, it sounds like Name is an attribute of the quote

Me, I wouldn’t use yet another surrogate key, I’d use something like

```
CUSTOMERHISTORY

CustomerId  int  not null  PK

QUOTE
CustomerId  int  not null  FK  PK 1/2
LoadedAt  datetime  not null  PK 2/2
Name  varchar(255)  no null
```

This does assume that you won’t have to deal with multiple quotes submitted at the exact same point in time—if that’s true, then you could benefit from `quoteID`… if, in fact, you actually need a primary key on this logging table. (Log tables are often be simple data dumps, with indexes for retrieval but no particular need to uniquely identify *and retrieve* any one single row.)

This still does not answer the “do not trust the primary key” issue. If it is a true and proper primary key as implemented in Microsoft SQL Server, then his not trusting it to provide true and accurate information is either (a) completely confused and misinformed, get yourself a new contractor, or (b) the rest of us who have been relying on it for the past 15+ years have been wrong all along. (Sure, his architecture would work, but it's needlessly complex.)

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Its a primary key, so no. 3. no, but `customerName` might change. 4. no, its the same data warehouse.

Comment: second set of questions: 1. yes, i need to know what was the name at that time of the customer that issues the quote. 2. see 1. 3. dunno, that is what im asking.

Comment: How about logging? Do you need to know how a customer's name has changed over time, or do you only need to know the most recent name used by/assigned to that customer?